# A rebus representing a Christian prayer

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, visual, rebus

This is a rebus representing a Christian prayer, I spent hours conceiving the idea and executing it.

The rebus itself is very simple, it contains 16 images, each corresponding to an English word, but the connection between the image and the word it represents might not be immediately obvious.

Your task is to identify the Christian prayer the rebus represents, note that I dropped many words because I have no idea how to represent those words.

[image]

Comment: Good puzzle, but as an atheist American who has been around religious people much of my life, in general there are around 3 or 4 prayers that I know pretty well. So by saying "A christian prayer", you're immediately narrowing my guessing from thousands of options for this puzzle to 3 or 4, and I could identify it based on that. You can hint your puzzle itself with the title without completely giving it away. Something like "Accept that not every puzzle is easy" is more enigmatic than "A christian prayer", but still would help get the answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's

> The Serenity Prayer – Reinhold Niebuhr

> God (**alpha omega**), grant (**genie wish**) me the serenity (**peace**)
>  to accept (**checkmark**) the things I cannot (**error**) change (**delta**),
>  the courage (**lion**) to change (**delta**) the things I can (**success**),
>  and (**&**) the wisdom (**lightbulb**) to know (**book**) the difference (**subtraction**).
>  The fingers pointing towards oneself all represent "me" or "I".